# DIFF = PL = TOP for surfaces (earliest references)

Tags: algebraic-topology, surfaces, geometric-topology, triangulation

I am looking for the original references that show that there is essentially a unique PL and smooth structure on a topological manifold of dimension 2.

- Radó ("Ueber den Begriff der Riemannschen Flache" 1925) for the existence and Kerékjártó ("Voriesullgen iiber Topologie", 1923) for the uniqueness show together that PL=TOP. This can be found in the celebrated book by Kirby–Siebenmann ["Foundational Essays on Topological Manifolds, Smoothings and Triangulations"](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/ks.pdf).
- For DIFF = PL , [this expository paper by Milnor](http://www.ams.org/notices/201106/rtx110600804p.pdf) points that the result follows from work from the '60s-'70s for manifolds of dimension $n<7$ (later references appear in [this upvoted post from MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/96670/classification-of-surfaces-and-the-top-diff-and-pl-categories-for-manifolds)). However I think that this might be a overkill to show DIFF = PL for surfaces. Is not there really an earlier argument?

At the end of the day I am really interested in the fact that DIFF=TOP for surfaces. Hatcher in his [The Kirby torus trick for surfaces](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/Papers/TorusTrick.pdf) says that

> The first proof that surfaces can be triangulated (and hence smoothed)
> is generally attributed to Radó in 1925.

Does the *"hence smoothed"* mean that DIFF=TOP for surfaces was already known in the 20s after Radó's work? If so, how does it follow?

Comment: See the 1960 Munkres reference I gave [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3606020/classification-of-surfaces-using-point-set-topology/3608795#3608795). I do not know an earlier one. [Smoothing a triangulated surface is easy, but approximating a PL homeomorphism by diffeomorphisms requires more work.]

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to put a smooth structure in a triangulated surface, please?

Comment: Do you know how to extends diffeomorphisms of the unit circle to those of the unit disk?

Comment: I do, but I genuinely do not see how this helps. At any rate I read in your linked answer that this would prove existence but not uniqueness of the smooth structure, is that right?

Comment: The link proves the harder result, the uniqueness. With a bit more thought, you realize that one can deduce the existence from the same proof as well. But you have to read the paper (JSTOR is free).